# Referencing a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 variables in a script tag that get populated with string values. 
I also have an `.each` loop that goes through each select box I have on the page. I want a way to append the index value of the loop to the name of the variable, and retrieve its value.

```
var secQuestion1 = "bla"
var secQuestion2 = "bla"

    selectbox.each(function( index ) {
       var question = ['secQuestion' + (index+1) ];
       console.log("question = ", ['secQuestion' + (index+1)] )
    });
```

I thought I might be able to use bracket notation to retrieve the value. 
Any ideas on how to do this, so on each index in the loop I would get my questions values?

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any jQuery here.  Have you looked at the documentation at all?  docs.jquery.com

Comment: Please add the code that assigns the value to `selectbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends in what context your code is running, if your variables are global then you can do

```
window['secQuestion' + (index+1)]
```

you can also put them in an object and access them that way

```
var obj = {
    secQuestion1: "bla",
    secQuestion2: "bla"
};
selectbox.each(function( index ) {
   console.log("question = ", obj['secQuestion' + (index+1)] )
});
```

Comment: That's a terrible, unmaintainable technique. Please stop advocating global variables to a newbie.

Comment: @Alex Weinstein, I answered his question, I did not advocate anything. Just because you don't like global variables does not mean people should not know about them and understand how to use them.

Comment: I here you Alex about the global variable using the window approach but the var obj approach works perfectly and the variable is not global as its inside a jquery ready function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an array here, for example:

```
var arrQuestions = ["question A", "question B", "questionC"];

selectbox.each(function( index ) {
   var question = arrQuestions[index];
}
```